# NSCountedSet generic function

Tags: swift, generics, nscountedset

To see how many `Person` objects with a specific identifier occur in an `NSCountedSet`, I created the following function:

```
public extension NSCountedSet {
    public func countFor(identifier: String) -> Int {
       let p = self.compactMap { $0 as? Person }.filter { $0. identifier == identifier }

       return self.count(for: p)
    }
}
```

Works great, but it is very specific for `Person`.

So I am trying to make it generic:

```
public func countFor<T: Identifiable >(type: T, identifier: String) -> Int {
    let p = self.compactMap { $0 as? T.Type }.filter { $0. identifier == identifier }

    return self.count(for: p)
}
```

`Person` conforms to a `Identifiable` protocol:

```
public protocol Identifiable {
    var identifier: String { get }
}
```

and:

```
extension Person: Identifiable {
    public var identifier: String {
        return name
    }
}
```

This gives me this error:

> Instance member 'identifier' cannot be used on type 'T'

And when I call this function, I get the following error:

> Argument type 'Person.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Identifiable'

What am I missing, is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: The problem is `$0 as? T.Type`. You can’t cast to a metatype.

Comment: @matt: I caught your - now deleted - answer with a good explanation about `Type`. Thanks for explaining it a bit in more detail.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted it because there wasn't enough detail in your question to make my answer meaningful. (Everything depends on how equatability and hashability are defined for a Person, and I had trouble understanding why you return `count(for:)` and not `p.count`.) But yes, your code would have compiled if you had said `type:T.Type` and removed `Type` from the `as?` cast.

Comment: @matt: Yes, good point about which `count` to use. It actually made me realize a small error in my code, since I want the number of `Person`. Now `let p = //` returns `[Person]`, and the count for that in the `NSCountedSet` is zero. So I need to use `self.count(for: p.first)` in the subsequent line.  Feels a bit cumbersome, though.

Comment: Right, I noticed the same thing. That's why I deleted my answer. As I said, without knowing how equatability and hashability are defined (clearly two Persons with different identifiers are not equal or we wouldn't be talking, but something must make them equal or you wouldn't be using a counted set, so what does make them equal? I have no idea because you didn't say), I can't give an intelligent response. — My deeper impulse would be to deny that you really need to use a counted set in the first place, but again, give no details, get no help.

Comment: Yes, `Person` was probably a bad example. In reality, I am working on a chemistry app, so I am counting elements in a molecule: how many C, how many H, etc. A counted set really helps here, I think.

Comment: I'm not persuaded. :) It sounds like a fun problem and I wish you'd ask about it as a separate question. Hint: It's easy to count things by feeding them into a dictionary that acts as a histogram.

Comment: Yes, a dictionary would work too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you even need `Generics` for that. You can simply do it like,

```
public func countFor(identifier: String) -> Int {
    let p = self.compactMap { $0 as? Identifiable }.filter { $0.identifier == identifier }
    return self.count(for: p)
}
```

In case, the `set` contains different types of `Identifiable` elements having same `identifiers`, you can resolve it using,

```
public func countFor<T: Identifiable>(type: T, identifier: String) -> Int {
    let p = self.compactMap { $0 as? T }.filter { $0.identifier == identifier }
    return self.count(for: p)
}
```

Comment: @matt The 2nd param will be required since it will be used to filter the elements.